# How to I fix libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so undefined symbol error?

Tags: gazebo, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently upgraded to the most recent packages of ROS hydro and now when I launch gazebo using "rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo" I'm getting the following error:

> gzserver: symbol lookup error:
> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEE

> gzclient: symbol lookup error:
> /opt/ros/hydro/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so:
> undefined symbol:
> _ZN3ros7package10getPluginsERKSsS2_RSt6vectorISsSaISsEE

Using c++filt or http://demangler.com/, I see that the following method is undefined:

> ros::package::getPlugins(std::string
> const&, std::string const&,
> std::vector<std::string,
> std::allocatorstd::string >&)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here are the ROS / Gazebo packages I have installed on my Ubuntu 12.04.4 64-bit computer:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep hydro | grep gazebo
ii  ros-hydro-gazebo3-msgs                      2.4.2-3precise                                                          Message and service data structures for interacting with Gazebo from ROS.
ii  ros-hydro-gazebo3-plugins                   2.4.2-3precise                                                          Robot-independent Gazebo plugins for sensors, motors and dynamic reconfigurable components.
ii  ros-hydro-gazebo3-ros                       2.4.2-3precise                                                          Provides ROS plugins that offer message and service publishers for interfacing with Gazebo through ROS. Formally simulator_gazebo/gazebo

$ dpkg -l | grep gazebo
ii  gazebo3                                     3.0.0-3~precise                                                         Open Source Robotics Simulator
ii  gazebo3-common                              3.0.0-3~precise                                                         Open Source Robotics Simulator - Shared files
ii  gazebo3-plugin-base                         3.0.0-3~precise                                                         Open Source Robotics Simulator - base plug-ins
ii  libgazebo-dev                               3.0.0-3~precise                                                         Open Source Robotics Simulator - Development Files
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175148/how-to-i-fix-libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so-undefined-symbol-error?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2014-06-26

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear liangfok,
I used the same configuration as your system (Ubuntu 12.04+gazebo3+ros-hydro-gazebo3) and sadly got the same error. Still don't know how to get through.
Does anyone help me out of this situation?

---

Originally posted by [danacity](https://answers.ros.org/users/19622/danacity/) with karma: 16 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on 2014-07-08**:
My current workaround is to create a script called run_gazebo:

https://bitbucket.org/cfok/hcrl_robot_models/src/23032a61c7299eaead51164eaf2703e0f4ab1868/hcrl_simulator/scripts/run_gazebo?at=develop

The script is started by a launch file:

https://bitbucket.org/cfok/hcrl_robot_models/src/23032a61c7299eaead51164eaf2703e0f4ab1868/stickbot_lowerleg_3dof/launch/gazebo.launch?at=develop

**Comment by [danacity](https://answers.ros.org/users/19622/danacity/) on 2014-07-09**:
It works for me. Thanks for your help.